# Covert ObjectID to displayname from Azure

Tags: bash, azure, powershell, objectid, azure-service-principal

Hi I'm trying to convert objectID to display name from logs in Azure. So the trouble I'm running into is that I have the ps script but can't get it to work for created account for my alerts.  It seems that the request body field keeps giving me errors.

```
        $responseBodyObject = ConvertFrom-Json $_.Properties.Content.responseBody
        $principalId = $responseBodyObject.properties.principalId
        Write-Host "PrincipalID: $($principalId)"
        $azUser = Get-AzADUser -ObjectId $principalId
        Write-Host "User: $($azUser.DisplayName)"
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
`Get-AzADUser : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is an empty string.
At C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxx.ps1:33 char:36
+         $azUser = Get-AzADUser -ObjectId $principalId
+                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Get-AzADUser
```

Comment: is there anything in ```$principalId``` ? Check it for ```$null```

Answer (score 1):

> Get-AzADUser : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is an empty string.

**The error message shows that Objectid has empty value.**

Make sure to check your **Principal ObjectID** whether it contains the valid **ObjectID** or not.

To check whether it is valid or not use below command

```bash
# use get-azaduser to get the objectid 
Get-AzADUser
# Search for specific user using Startwith filter
Get-AzADUser -StartsWith demo
```

#### workaround:

Here i am using both **ObjectId** and **UserPrinicipalName**

#### using ObjectID

[image]

#### using UserPrinicipalName

[image]